# How to open compose mail?

Tags: iphone

I created two buttons named `supportweb` and `email`, and under these buttons I wrote the code as:

```
- (void) supportweb
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fitzgerlad.com"]];
}

 - (void) email
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"support@fitzgerlad.com"]];
}
```

`supportweb` is opened normally, but `email` is not opened. What is the problem? Please help me. How can I solve this? Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail url format is `mailto:support@fitzgerlad.com`.

But, consider using [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to send email directly in your app.

Comment: it cant work, can u pls send link or post some code to open composemail

Comment: @MaheshBabu: no, you need to post more information about what you're trying. What does "can't work" mean?